# Strip off specific parameter from URL's querystring

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla, query-string

I have some links in a Powerpoint presentation, and for some reason, when those links get clicked, it adds a return parameter to the URL. Well, that return parameter is causing my Joomla site's MVC pattern to get bungled.

What's an efficient way to strip off this return parameter using PHP?

Example:
`http://mydomain.example/index.php?id=115&Itemid=283&return=aHR0cDovL2NvbW11bml0`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beautiful way to remove GET-variables with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251582/beautiful-way-to-remove-get-variables-with-php)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The safest "correct" method would be:

1. Parse the url into an array with [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url)
2. Extract the query portion, decompose that into an array using [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)
3. Delete the query parameters you want by `unset()` them from the array
4. Rebuild the original url using [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query)

Quick and dirty is to use a string search/replace and/or regex to kill off the value.

Comment: mmm weird, my `$parsedurl['query']` is a single string containing all params

Comment: example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251582/beautiful-way-to-remove-get-variables-with-php/1251597#1251597

Comment: can you give an example of scenario in which the dirty regex would fail ?

Comment: Please give an example?

Comment: parse_url() is buggy. It is not safe to use it at all.

Comment: [Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937478/strip-off-url-parameter-with-php/71202513#71202513)

Answer (score 94):

In a different thread Justin suggests that the fastest way is to use [strtok()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)

```
 $url = strtok($url, '?');
```

See his full answer with speed tests as well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1251650/452515

Comment: The question was how to remove the specific GET variable `return` and not to remove all GET variables.

Answer (score 36):

This is to complement **Marc B**'s answer with an example, while it may look quite long, it's a safe way to remove a parameter. In this example we remove `page_number`

```
<?php
$x = 'http://url.example/search/?location=london&page_number=1';

$parsed = parse_url($x);
$query = $parsed['query'];

parse_str($query, $params);

unset($params['page_number']);
$string = http_build_query($params);
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: Thank you Sergey, and thank you @Marc B, brilliant help.

Comment: Comment for anyone who finds themselves using this code that this just returns the query string (minus the parameter you've stripped out.)  You won't have a full url any more, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 17):

```
function removeParam($url, $param) {
    $url = preg_replace('/(&|\?)'.preg_quote($param).'=[^&]*$/', '', $url);
    $url = preg_replace('/(&|\?)'.preg_quote($param).'=[^&]*&/', '$1', $url);
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: Agreed, exactly what I was looking for.  regex is my weakness, but I knew it was the answer I needed.

Comment: If the url has a #hash at the end following the target parameter, this function will strip it off as well. Careful what you copy / paste, this answer has been out there for 8 years on a question with 150k views and no one has noticed.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like most of the answers here will strip out the hash.

Answer (score 14):

```
parse_str($queryString, $vars);
unset($vars['return']);
$queryString = http_build_query($vars);
```

[`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) parses a query string, [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) creates a query string.

Answer (score 12):

Procedural Implementation of [Marc B's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4937561/7198013) Answer after refining [Sergey Telshevsky's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27689796/7198013) Answer.

```
function strip_param_from_url($url, $param)
{
    $base_url = strtok($url, '?');                   // Get the base URL
    $parsed_url = parse_url($url);                   // Parse it
                               // Add missing {
    if(array_key_exists('query',$parsed_url)) {      // Only execute if there are parameters
        $query = $parsed_url['query'];               // Get the query string
        parse_str($query, $parameters);              // Convert Parameters into array
        unset($parameters[$param]);                  // Delete the one you want
        $new_query = http_build_query($parameters);  // Rebuilt query string
        $url =$base_url.'?'.$new_query;              // Finally URL is ready
    }
    return $url;            
}

// Usage
echo strip_param_from_url( 'http://url.example/search/?location=london&page_number=1', 'location' )
```

Comment: It causes an error when passed a url without querystring.

Comment: It also leaves the '?' which could cause a problem later down the line

Answer (score 9):

You could do a `preg_replace` like:

```
$new_url = preg_replace('/&?return=[^&]*/', '', $old_url);
```

Comment: Not a good idea if "?return=" is not the last parameter. A query like "urlerror.com/index.php?return=1&test=abc" would get changed to "urlerror.com/index.php&test=abc"

Comment: preg_replace('/return=[^&]?&?/i', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

Comment: This answer is wrong. Analysis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47527628/318765

Answer (score 7):

Here is the actual code for what's described above as the "the safest 'correct' method"...

```
function reduce_query($uri = '') {
    $kill_params = array('gclid');

    $uri_array = parse_url($uri);
    if (isset($uri_array['query'])) {
        // Do the chopping.
        $params = array();
        foreach (explode('&', $uri_array['query']) as $param) {
          $item = explode('=', $param);
          if (!in_array($item[0], $kill_params)) {
            $params[$item[0]] = isset($item[1]) ? $item[1] : '';
          }
        }
        // Sort the parameter array to maximize cache hits.
        ksort($params);
        // Build new URL (no hosts, domains, or fragments involved).
        $new_uri = '';
        if ($uri_array['path']) {
          $new_uri = $uri_array['path'];
        }
        if (count($params) > 0) {
          // Wish there was a more elegant option.
          $new_uri .= '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params));
        }
        return $new_uri;
    }
    return $uri;
}

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = reduce_query($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

However, since this will likely exist prior to the bootstrap of your application, you should probably put it into an anonymous function. Like this...

```
call_user_func(function($uri) {
    $kill_params = array('gclid');

    $uri_array = parse_url($uri);
    if (isset($uri_array['query'])) {
        // Do the chopping.
        $params = array();
        foreach (explode('&', $uri_array['query']) as $param) {
          $item = explode('=', $param);
          if (!in_array($item[0], $kill_params)) {
            $params[$item[0]] = isset($item[1]) ? $item[1] : '';
          }
        }
        // Sort the parameter array to maximize cache hits.
        ksort($params);
        // Build new URL (no hosts, domains, or fragments involved).
        $new_uri = '';
        if ($uri_array['path']) {
          $new_uri = $uri_array['path'];
        }
        if (count($params) > 0) {
          // Wish there was a more elegant option.
          $new_uri .= '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params));
        }
        // Update server variable.
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $new_uri;

    }
}, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

NOTE: Updated with `urldecode()` to avoid double encoding `via http_build_query()` function.
NOTE: Updated with `ksort()` to allow params with no value without an error.

Comment: Great examples! Note to others: the 'gclid' in the $kill_params array is what will be removed from the query string portion of the uri. Note also that this method of rebuilding the url may not be complete. Also, I have just come across another approach that may work better for splitting and rejoining more modern URIs than using parse_url(); here: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/05/php_tip_how_parse_and_build_urls

Answer (score 5):

This one of many ways, not tested, but should work.

```
$link = 'http://mydomain.example/index.php?id=115&Itemid=283&return=aHR0cDovL2NvbW11bml0';
$linkParts = explode('&return=', $link);
$link = $linkParts[0];
```

Comment: This solution is counting for `return` to be at the last position, if that's not the case you will lose all the other params from `return` param as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
$var = preg_replace( "/return=[^&]+/", "", $var ); 
$var = preg_replace( "/&{2,}/", "&", $var );
```

Second line will just replace && to &

Comment: Did you down vote everyone else? Not pointing fingers, but everyone has a -1 except for you...

Comment: If you click on the number of votes it will give you a break down of the votes (I think you need a higher reputation to do this). If you didn't do it, that's cool, just thought it was peculiar that everyone has a -1 except for you.

Comment: Add a 3-rd "preg_replace" to replace "?&" to "?", like:  
`$var = preg_replace("/\?&/", "?", $var);`

Answer (score 4):

Wow, there are a lot of examples here.  I am providing one that does some error handling.  It rebuilds and returns the entire URL with the query-string-param-to-be-removed, removed.  It also provides a bonus function that builds the current URL on the fly.  Tested, works!

Credit to [Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) for the steps.  This is a complete solution to [tpow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462307/tpow)'s "strip off this return parameter" original question -- might be handy for beginners, trying to avoid PHP gotchas. :-)

```
<?php

function currenturl_without_queryparam( $queryparamkey ) {
    $current_url = current_url();
    $parsed_url = parse_url( $current_url );
    if( array_key_exists( 'query', $parsed_url )) {
        $query_portion = $parsed_url['query'];
    } else {
        return $current_url;
    }

    parse_str( $query_portion, $query_array );

    if( array_key_exists( $queryparamkey , $query_array ) ) {
        unset( $query_array[$queryparamkey] );
        $q = ( count( $query_array ) === 0 ) ? '' : '?';
        return $parsed_url['scheme'] . '://' . $parsed_url['host'] . $parsed_url['path'] . $q . http_build_query( $query_array );
    } else {
        return $current_url;
    }
}

function current_url() {
    $current_url = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
    return $current_url;
}

echo currenturl_without_queryparam( 'key' );

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

very simple

```
$link = "http://example.com/index.php?id=115&Itemid=283&return=aHR0cDovL2NvbW11bml0"
echo substr($link, 0, strpos($link, "return") - 1);
//output : http://example.com/index.php?id=115&Itemid=283
```

Answer (score 3):

@MarcB mentioned that it is dirty to use regex to remove an url parameter. And yes it is, because it's not as easy as it looks:

```
$urls = array(
  'example.com/?foo=bar',
  'example.com/?bar=foo&foo=bar',
  'example.com/?foo=bar&bar=foo',
);

echo 'Original' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($urls as $url) {
  echo $url . PHP_EOL;
}

echo PHP_EOL . '@AaronHathaway' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($urls as $url) {
  echo preg_replace('#&?foo=[^&]*#', null, $url) . PHP_EOL;
}

echo PHP_EOL . '@SergeS' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($urls as $url) {
  echo preg_replace( "/&{2,}/", "&", preg_replace( "/foo=[^&]+/", "", $url)) . PHP_EOL;
}

echo PHP_EOL . '@Justin' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($urls as $url) {
  echo preg_replace('/([?&])foo=[^&]+(&|$)/', '$1', $url) . PHP_EOL;
}

echo PHP_EOL . '@kraftb' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($urls as $url) {
  echo preg_replace('/(&|\?)foo=[^&]*&/', '$1', preg_replace('/(&|\?)foo=[^&]*$/', '', $url)) . PHP_EOL;
}

echo PHP_EOL . 'My version' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($urls as $url) {
  echo str_replace('/&', '/?', preg_replace('#[&?]foo=[^&]*#', null, $url)) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

returns:

```
Original
example.com/?foo=bar
example.com/?bar=foo&foo=bar
example.com/?foo=bar&bar=foo

@AaronHathaway
example.com/?
example.com/?bar=foo
example.com/?&bar=foo

@SergeS
example.com/?
example.com/?bar=foo&
example.com/?&bar=foo

@Justin
example.com/?
example.com/?bar=foo&
example.com/?bar=foo

@kraftb
example.com/
example.com/?bar=foo
example.com/?bar=foo

My version
example.com/
example.com/?bar=foo
example.com/?bar=foo
```

As you can see only @kraftb posted a correct answer using regex and my version is a little bit smaller.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the examples posted are so extensive. This is what I use on my projects.

```
function removeQueryParameter($url, $param){
    list($baseUrl, $urlQuery) = explode('?', $url, 2);
    parse_str($urlQuery, $urlQueryArr);
    unset($urlQueryArr[$param]);

    if(count($urlQueryArr))
        return $baseUrl.'?'.http_build_query($urlQueryArr);
    else
        return $baseUrl;
}
```

Comment: It fails when there is no "?" in the URL. I got "Undefined offset: 1"

Comment: The function is to remove query parameter, in my case I was expecting one - always. If that's not the case for you, you can add a check for that.

Answer (score 2):

**Remove Get Parameters From Current Page**

```
<?php
$url_dir=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 

$url_dir_no_get_param= explode("?",$url_dir)[0];

echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$url_dir_no_get_param;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
public function removeQueryParam(string $url, string $param): string
{
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

    if (isset($parsedUrl[$param])) {
        $baseUrl = strtok($url, '?');
        parse_str(parse_url($url)['query'], $query);
        unset($query[$param]);
        return sprintf('%s?%s',
            $baseUrl,
            http_build_query($query)
        );
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Simple solution that will work for every url

With this solution `$url` format or parameter position doesn't matter, as an example I added another parameter and anchor at the end of `$url`:

```
https://example.com/index.php?id=115&Itemid=283&return=aHR0cDovL2NvbW11bml0&bonus=test#test2
```

**Here is the simple solution:**

```
$url = 'https://example.com/index.php?id=115&Itemid=283&return=aHR0cDovL2NvbW11bml0&bonus=test#test2';

$url_query_stirng = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str( $url_query_stirng, $url_parsed_query );
unset($url_parsed_query['return']);
$url = str_replace( $url_query_stirng, http_build_query( $url_parsed_query ), $url );

echo $url;
```

Final result for `$url` string is:

```
https://example.com/index.php?id=115&Itemid=283&bonus=test#test2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_attribute($url,$attribute)
 {
    $url=explode('?',$url);
    $new_parameters=false;
    if(isset($url[1]))
    {
        $params=explode('&',$url[1]);
        $new_parameters=ra($params,$attribute);
    }
    $construct_parameters=($new_parameters && $new_parameters!='' ) ? ('?'.$new_parameters):'';
    return $new_url=$url[0].$construct_parameters;
 }
 function ra($params,$attr)
    {   $attr=$attr.'=';
        $new_params=array();

        for($i=0;$i<count($params);$i++)
        {   
            $pos=strpos($params[$i],$attr);

            if($pos===false)
            $new_params[]=$params[$i];

        }
        if(count($new_params)>0)
        return implode('&',$new_params);
        else 
        return false; 
     }
```

//just copy the above code and  just call this function like this to get new url without particular parameter

echo remove_attribute($url,'delete_params'); // gives new url without that parameter

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but if you only want to remove one or few named url parameter you can use this function:

```
function RemoveGet_Regex($variable, $rewritten_url): string {
    $rewritten_url = preg_replace("/(\?)$/", "", preg_replace("/\?&/", "?", preg_replace("/((?<=\?)|&){$variable}=[\w]*/i", "", $rewritten_url)));
    return $rewritten_url;
}
function RemoveGet($name): void {
    $rewritten_url = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    if(is_array($name)) {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
            $rewritten_url = RemoveGet_Regex($name[$i], $rewritten_url);
            $is_set[] = isset($_GET[$name[$i]]);
        }
        $array_filtered = array_filter($is_set);
        if (!empty($array_filtered)) {
            header("Location: ".$rewritten_url);
        }
    }
    else {
        $rewritten_url = RemoveGet_Regex($name, $rewritten_url);
        if(isset($_GET[$name])) {
            header("Location: ".$rewritten_url);
        }
    }
}
```

In the first function `preg_replace("/((?<=\?)|&){$variable}=[\w]*/i", "", $rewritten_url)` will remove the get parameter, and the others will tidy it up. The second function will then redirect.

`RemoveGet("id");` will remove the `id=whatever` from the url. The function can also work with arrays. For your example,

`Remove(array("id","Item","return"));`

Answer (score 0):

To strip any parameter from the url using PHP script you need to follow this script:

```
 function getNewArray($array,$k){
        $dataArray = $array;
        unset($array[$k]);
        $dataArray = $array;
        return $dataArray;  
    }
    
function getFullURL(){
        return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    }

 

     $url = getFullURL(); 
      $url_components = parse_url($url);
      
      // Use parse_str() function to parse the
      // string passed via URL
      parse_str($url_components['query'], $params);
      print_r($params); 

    <ul>
    <?php foreach($params as $k=>$v){?>
    <?php 
    
    $newArray = getNewArray($params,$k);
    $parameters  = http_build_query($newArray);
    $newURL = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$parameters;
     ?>
    <li><?=$v;?> <a href="<?=$newURL;?>">X</a>
    <?php }?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

here is functions optimized for speed. But this functions DO NOT remove arrays like `a[]=x&a[1]bb=y&a[2]=z` by array name.

```
function removeQueryParam($query, $param)
{
    $quoted_param = preg_quote($param, '/');
    $pattern = "/(^$quoted_param=[^&]*&?)|(&$quoted_param=[^&]*)/";
    return preg_replace($pattern, '', $query);
}

function removeQueryParams($query, array $params)
{
    if ($params)
    {
        $pattern = '/';
        foreach ($params as $param)
        {
            $quoted_param = preg_quote($param, '/');
            $pattern .= "(^$quoted_param=[^&]*&?)|(&$quoted_param=[^&]*)|";
        }
        $pattern[-1] = '/';
        return preg_replace($pattern, '', $query);  
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing in PHP to remove the GET element from the URL when the pagination reached page 1, so I created a function in a helper which I call every time in the main controller.

```
function fixPagination(){
    //check if exist page parameter and page number == 1
    if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == '1'){
        //parse url
        $parseUrl = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        parse_str($parseUrl['query'], $newParsedUrl);
        //unset the get page element and keep the other get elements, such as brand
        unset($newParsedUrl['page']);
        $newQueryString = http_build_query($newParsedUrl);
        //check if have another get elements
        if(empty($newQueryString)){
            $newFixUrl = base_url().$parseUrl['path'];
        }else{
            $newFixUrl = base_url().$parseUrl['path'].'?'.$newQueryString;
        }
        //redirect to new url with 301 code
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: ".$newFixUrl);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Whip's implementation of the marked solution, I added some extra options:

1. An option to return the base URL - if set to false it will only return the re-built query string
2. An option to exclude the full URL, which will use the query string alone by default.
3. Changed the `$param` to an array to be able to exclude multiple query string parameters.

```php
function removeQueryParameters($params = array(), $returnBaseURL = false, $url = null)
{
    $url = is_null($url) ? '?' . $_GET : $url;
    list($baseUrl, $urlQuery) = explode('?', $url, 2);
    parse_str($urlQuery, $urlQueryArr);
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        unset($urlQueryArr[$param]);
    }

    if (count($urlQueryArr)) {
        if ($returnBaseURL) {
            return $baseUrl . '?' . http_build_query($urlQueryArr);
        } else {
            return http_build_query($urlQueryArr);
        }
    } else {
        return $baseUrl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<? if(isset($_GET['i'])){unset($_GET['i']); header('location:/');} ?>
```

This will remove the 'i' parameter from the URL. Change the 'i's to whatever you need.