# How to pass more than one variable in the URL bar using PHP?

Tags: php, url, variables

I want to pass more than one variable in the URL bar using PHP, however I want one of the variables to be added onto another existing variable in the URL bar.

For example:
Let's say you have: test.php?u=2 and let's suppose one of the fields is age. Once I click submit I want the URL to look like test.php?u=2&age=22 but on the same page.

How could I do this? Would I have to redirect the user again?

Comment: Is your question about how to construct the URL?

Comment: No. My question is how do I add another variable to the same URL.

Comment: With or without reloading the page? The latter is not possible

Comment: With reloading the same page.

Comment: @master from PHP, a header redirect is your only choice then. However, building the URL is more tricky than adding `&age=22` to the query string if you want to do it properly.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the instant help. I'll try to see what I can do and if it doesn't work I'll reply back. EDIT: I already built the URL, it's just that I want another variable on the same page instead of redirecting the user.

Comment: See this question for the safest way to build the new query string: [Strip off URL parameter with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4937478) It's about the exact opposite of what you want, but the approach is the same

Answer (score 1):

`<form method="get" action="?">` - use this as your form tag. It'll submit to the same page, with all the form values in the querystring, accessible via `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code that injects all request variables into the form that the button submits. For example:

```
<form ... >
    <?php foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
              echo sprintf('<input type="hidden" name="%s" value="%s" />', 
                  htmlspecialchars($key),
                  htmlspecialchars($value));
          }
    ?>
<!-- the one you want to add follows -->
<input type="hidden" name="age" value="22" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

It isn't pretty, but it works (if you don't mind that the vars from either `$_GET` or `$_POST` will actually end up being submitted with other method, whichever one it is the form uses).