# How can remove the particular parameters in URL using Regex

Tags: php, regex, url

We are not able to strip the particular parameters in URL, please look at the URL.

> http://www.globalseopulse.com/&sa=U&ei=u7RWUJniFcfTrQejp4DACw&ved=0CBMQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEWLiKXbuVg6N165ETGYP3F1K0Qfw

In our code, it automatically adds the parameters:

> &sa=U&ei=u7RWUJniFcfTrQejp4DACw&ved=0CBMQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEWLiKXbuVg6N165ETGYP3F1K0Qfw

We do not need these parameters in our program. Please provide me the suitable method in which we can remove the additional parameters within the loop .

Thanks

PPS

Comment: Possibly a dupe of [Beautiful way to remove GET-variables with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251582/beautiful-way-to-remove-get-variables-with-php) and [Strip off URL parameter with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937478/strip-off-url-parameter-with-php)

Comment: please check the URL, it's not having "?" in the URL.

Comment: OK, have added string-manipulation- (rather than URL manipulation-) based answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://www.globalseopulse.com/&sa=U&ei=u7RWUJniFcfTrQejp4DACw&ved=0CBMQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEWLiKXbuVg6N165ETGYP3F1K0Qfw";
$pieces = explode("&", $url, 1);
$urlWithoutParameters = $pieces[0];
```

Comment: it's ok, but that's not a right for everytime. if we have a already parameter in the URL then our this script is not giving the right data. like if our URL will be "www.globalseopulse.com/resources.html?a=somevalue&sa=U&ei=u7RWUJniFcfTrQejp4DACw&ved=0CBYQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNF_y6UlnnjEZwniTcOsA0etbcAp3Q" then we are not able to remove this "&sa=U&ei=u7RWUJniFcfTrQejp4DACw&ved=0CBYQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNF_y6UlnnjEZwniTcOsA0etbcAp3Q"