# How to avoid showing the parameter for a .php file when send it via address bar

Tags: php

is possible to avoid showing the parameter for a .php file when send it via address bar?
but still send the parameter to other .php  file?

[avoid showing parameters for .php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk1lE.png)

Comment: Use the POST method instead of GET.

Comment: Or use sessions. Though that would be quite a bit more work.

Comment: What is specific to PHP about URLs containing a *query (string)*? What would be a legitimate use of hiding from a user the information you make her computer spill?

Comment: What would you achieve by "hiding" such parameters? And don't say you want to "increase security" or prevent people from accessing records they should not be allowed to see now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use $_POST instead of $_GET ?
$_POST is not showing on URLs. If you don't want to use $_POST I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937478/strip-off-url-parameter-with-php)

Comment: ([RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) (2014) allows a *payload within a GET request message*.)