# Remove string from URL when site is loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to remove specific or full parameters from the URL of the website when it is actively loading in the browser. I want to do this because some website including additional strings.

```
https://www.example.com/?gclid=anything
https://www.example.com/?fbclid=anything
https://www.example.com/?msclid=anything
```

These are the tokens sent by third party like Google, Facebook, etc. I want to remove that.

For example, if peoples click my link on facebook `https://www.example.com/` than Facebook will include `https://www.example.com/?fbclid=something` but i want `?fbclid=something` should be removed and peoples land to `https://www.example.com/` instead of `https://www.example.com/?fbclid=something`

My code :

```
$url = strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?');
```

I have already checked [Strip off URL parameter with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937478/strip-off-url-parameter-with-php) & [How to remove the querystring and get only the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969645/how-to-remove-the-querystring-and-get-only-the-url) but no success.

Please suggest me how to achieve this using PHP or JavaScript.

Comment: You can start using parse_url https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php . With this function you can easily verify if your site is visited with any parameters. If so, you can simply use a `header("location......")` again without the parameters. Maybe, you can use some magic with `.htaccess` as well. But that's beyond my knowledge :)

Comment: You could do this in js: `window.history.pushState('', '', '/')` . You can even test in in developer console at your site after fb-redirect

Comment: @Techno This works but it also removing the premalink. `example.com/page.php?something` instead of `example.com/page.php`. it displaying `example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is history.pushState

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

The below example will change the url `https://www.example.com/?fbclid=something` to `https://www.example.com/`

```
window.history.pushState({}, '', '/');
```

Comment: This works but it also removing the premalink. `example.com/page.php?something` instead of `example.com/page.php`. it displaying `example.com`

Comment: then you would want window.history.pushState({}, '', 'page.php');

Comment: Then i have to place this code every time for different pages. it like `WordPress` website. I can place in header or footer and work for all the pages & post.

Comment: Then you would want to parse the path from the url https://dmitripavlutin.com/parse-url-javascript/#5-pathname

Comment: you could do something like window.history.pushState({}, '', window.location.pathname);

Comment: And one more question. What if i want to remove specific string from URL. not all string. How i can use your code to achieve it?

Comment: if you wanted to parse the query parameters (?name=val&name2=val2) you would use window.location.search to get everything from the url after the "?" then you would replace the text you want removed... then you would use the result as the last parameter in the window.history.pushState method

Comment: if you're happy with the answer please flag it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

For Reference :

Answer by @dvicemuse & @Techno

```
<script>
//window.history.pushState('', '', '/');
//window.history.pushState({}, '', '/'); 
window.history.pushState({}, '', window.location.pathname);
</script>
```

Documents :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState
- https://dmitripavlutin.com/parse-url-javascript/#5-pathname