# PHP Remove # using preg

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to remove the # from a twitter name.

Tried this:

```
$name = '#mytwitter';
$str = preg_replace('/\#/', ' ', $name);
```

Sure this is a simple fix , but Google didn't help. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use `preg_replace`, just use `str_replace`:

```
str_replace('#','',$name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you escaping `#`?

```
$name = '#mytwitter';
$str = preg_replace('/#/', ' ', $name);
```

**Edit**: Your original code does work, too. Note that `preg_replace` returns the substituted string but doesn't change the original. The value of `$str` is " mytwitter".

Comment: `preg_replace` is much slower than `str_replace`, there is no need to use it here

Comment: @Jaitsu: Certainly, but there is always a trade-off between fixing and rewriting the code. It is not obvious at all which the original poster would benefit the most from.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to escape `#`.

```
$str = preg_replace('/#/', '', $name);
```

However, for a simple character removal, you are better off using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace). It's faster for those situations.

```
$str = str_replace('#', '', $name);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [strtok](http://php.net/strtok) for this, as it's more performant. Just use it like so:

```
$str = strtok('#mytwitter', '#');
```

Here are some benchmarks i just ran (50000 iterations):

```
strreplace execution time: 0.068472146987915 seconds
preg_replace execution time: 0.12657809257507 seconds
strtok execution time: 0.043070077896118 seconds
```

The script i used to benchmark is (taken from [Beautiful way to remove GET-variables with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251582/beautiful-way-to-remove-get-variables-with-php)):

```
<?php

$number_of_tests = 50000;

// str_replace
$mtime = microtime();
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
$starttime = $mtime;

for($i = 0; $i < $number_of_tests; $i++){
    $str = "#mytwitter";
    $str = str_replace('#' , '', $str);
}
$mtime = microtime();
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
$endtime = $mtime;
$totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
echo "strreplace execution time: ".$totaltime." seconds;  <br />";

// preg_replace
$mtime = microtime();
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
$starttime = $mtime;

for($i = 0; $i < $number_of_tests; $i++){
    $str = "#mytwitter";
    $str = preg_replace('/#/', ' ', $str);
}
$mtime = microtime();
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
$endtime = $mtime;
$totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
echo "preg_replace execution time: ".$totaltime." seconds;  <br />";

// strtok
$mtime = microtime();
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
$starttime = $mtime;

for($i = 0; $i < $number_of_tests; $i++){
    $str = "#mytwitter";
    $str = strtok($str, "#");
}
$mtime = microtime();
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
$endtime = $mtime;
$totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
echo "strtok execution time: ".$totaltime." seconds; <br />";

  [1]: http://php.net/strtok
```

Comment: thanks for this, will look into it, always handy to be able to speed things up!