# Function to remove GET variable with php

Tags: php, string

i have this URI.

> http://localhost/index.php?properties&status=av&page=1

i am fetching basename of the URI using following code.

```
$basename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

the above code gives me following string.

> index.php?properties&status=av&page=1

i would want to remove the last variable from the string i.e `&page=1`. please note the value for `page` will not always be `1`. keeping this in mind i would want to trim the variable this way.

> Trim from the last position of the string till the first delimiter i.e `&`

**Update :**

I would like to remove `&page=1` from the string, no matter in which position it is on.

how do i do this?

Comment: What if it's `index.php?properties&page=1&status=av` instead? Do you want to remove `page` or `status`?

Comment: Take a look here, this may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251582/beautiful-way-to-remove-get-variables-with-php

Comment: @mercator i would want to remove page

Comment: if you're just doing pagination, check `$_GET['page']` and increment it.

Comment: @dnagirl, sounds good but you are explaining out of context. i knew i could do that :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of hacking around with regular expression you should parse the string as an url (what it is)

```
$string = 'index.php?properties&status=av&page=1';

$parts = parse_url($string);

$queryParams = array();
parse_str($parts['query'], $queryParams);
```

Now just remove the parameter

```
unset($queryParams['page']);
```

and rebuild the url

```
$queryString = http_build_query($queryParams);
$url = $parts['path'] . '?' . $queryString;
```

Comment: this seriously looks good. and to be frank i was expecting to do something like this.

Comment: Very nice, worked perfectly for me as well! Thank you KingCrunch :)

Comment: You can also do `parse_str(html_entity_decode($parts['query']), $queryParams);` to preserve the `&` when echo'ing it out

Answer (score 3):

There are many roads that lead to Rome. I'd do it with a RegEx:

```
$myString = 'index.php?properties&status=av&page=1';
$myNewString = preg_replace("/\&[a-z0-9]+=[0-9]+$/i","",$myString);
```

if you only want the `&page=1`-type parameters, the last line would be

```
$myNewString = preg_replace("/\&page=[0-9]+/i","",$myString);
```

if you also want to get rid of the possibility that page is the only or first parameter:

```
$myNewString = preg_replace("/[\&]*page=[0-9]+/i","",$myString);
```

Comment: i appreciate your help and sorry for not mentioning this before but this will only remove the last variable from the string, wheras i am looking to remove the `&page=1` variable regardless of it's position.

Comment: preg_replace("/\&page=[0-9]+/i","",$myString); ... only the page :)

Comment: `index.php?page=123&properties&status=av`?

Comment: He wanted to match the &, so this was included ... but hell, I will change ;)

Comment: `index.php?momomomooonsterpage=123&properties&status=av`? (=> `index.php?momomomooonster&properties&status=av`;)) Regular expressions have many pitfalls. I don't want to embarrass you, but such things often leads to weird behavior later, that are hard to track down.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you guys but i think i have found the better solution, @KingCrunch had suggested a solution i extended and converted it into function. the below function can possibly remove or unset any URI variable without any regex hacks being used. i am posting it as it might help someone.

```
function unset_uri_var($variable, $uri) {   
    $parseUri = parse_url($uri);
    $arrayUri = array();
    parse_str($parseUri['query'], $arrayUri);
    unset($arrayUri[$variable]);
    $newUri = http_build_query($arrayUri);
    $newUri = $parseUri['path'].'?'.$newUri;
    return $newUri;
}
```

now consider the following uri

```
index.php?properties&status=av&page=1

//To remove properties variable
$url = unset_uri_var('properties', basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
//Outputs index.php?page=1&status=av

//To remove page variable
$url = unset_uri_var('page', basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
//Outputs index.php?properties=&status=av
```

hope this helps someone. and thank you @KingKrunch for your solution :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$pos = strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '&');    
$url = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, $pos - 1);
```

[Documentation for strrpos.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

Comment: I think you mean `strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '&')`

Comment: although this will work but it will just remove the last Variable. i am sorry for not stating this before but i would like to trim `$page=1` regardless of it's position it may occur before `status=av` or after.

Comment: You can do it with built in PHP functions, but it's better to use a regular expression in that case.

Comment: @root45, i am little weaker in regex. i would appreciate if you could help me on this :)

Comment: @root45 ... you could at least have the motivation to change my variable name before you 'rip off' my post directly below ;)

Comment: @Martin Hohenberg, you caught me. I upvoted your answer. I'll delete my comment if you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

Regex that works on every possible situation: **`/(&|(?<=\?))page=.*?(?=&|$)/`**. [Here's example code](http://ideone.com/clone/6dRp8):

```
$regex = '/(&|(?<=\?))page=.*?(?=&|$)/';
$urls = array(
        'index.php?properties&status=av&page=1',
        'index.php?properties&page=1&status=av',
        'index.php?page=1',
);
foreach($urls as $url) {
        echo preg_replace($regex, '', $url), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
index.php?properties&status=av
index.php?properties&status=av
index.php?
```

Regex explanation:

- `(&|(?<=\?))` -- either match a `&` or a `?`, but if it's a `?`, don't put it in the match and just ignore it (you don't want urls like `index.php&status=av`)
- `page=.*?` -- matches `page=[...]`
- `(?=&|$)` -- look for a `&` or the end of the string (`$`), but don't include them for the replacement (this group helps the previous one find out exactly where to stop matching)

Comment: i appreciate that @Gabi Purcaru, or how about the extended solution from KingCrunch, check my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this causes problems in PHP < 5.2.2

Comment: Best options !
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RegEx (as Chris suggests) but it's not the most efficient solution (lots of overhead using that engine... it's easy to do with some string parsing:

```
<?php
//$url="http://localhost/index.php?properties&status=av&page=1";
$base=basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

echo "Basename yields: $base<br />";

//Find the last ampersand
$lastAmp=strrpos($base,"&");

//Filter, catch no ampersands found
$removeLast=($lastAmp===false?$base:substr($base,0,$lastAmp));

echo "Without Last Parameter: $removeLast<br />";
?>
```

The trick is, can you guarantee that `$page` will be stuck on the end?  If it is - great, if it isn't... what you asked for may not always solve the problem.