# preg_replace for Get Parameter - /index.php?color=blue&size=xl

Tags: php, get, preg-replace

I have this url /index.php?color=blue&size=xl

to get rid of the get parameter, I use this code:

```
$done = preg_replace('/(.*)(\?|&)color=[^&]*(?(1)&|)?/i', "$1", $url);
echo $done;
"output: index.phpsize=xl"
```

Now I need to clean the "size" part too. Have tried with two lines of preg_replace, but it doesn´t work.

```
$done = preg_replace('/(.*)(\?|&)color=[^&]*(?(1)&|)?/i', "$1", $url);
echo $done;
$done2 = preg_replace('/(.*)(\?|&)size=[^&]*(?(1)&|)?/i', "$1", $done);
```

Edit: I really need a solution where I can clean the exact parameter "color" or "size".

Sometimes I will only delete one of them.

Edit2:
Have this solution:

```
// Url is: index.php?color=black&size=xl&price=20

function removeqsvar($url, $varname) {
return preg_replace('/([?&])'.$varname.'=[^&]+(&|$)/','$1',$url);
}
$url = removeqsvar($url, color);
echo removeqsvar($url, price);

// will output: index.php?size=xl
```

Thank you all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beautiful way to remove GET-variables with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251582/beautiful-way-to-remove-get-variables-with-php)

Comment: do you know, how to remove 2 variables from 3?

Comment: Sure, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17240988/862594

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow you to exactly specify which parameters to remove using the `$remove` array. It works by parsing the URL with [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url), then grabbing the query string and parsing it with [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str).

From there, it's straightforward - Iterate over the parameters in the URL, if one of them is in the `$remove` array, then delete it from the `$params` array. By the end, if we have parameters to add to the URL, we add them back with [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query).

```
$url = '/index.php?color=blue&size=xl'; // Your input URL
$remove = array( 'color', 'size'); // Change this to remove what you want

$parts = parse_url( $url);
parse_str( $parts['query'], $params);

foreach( $params as $k => $v) {
    if( in_array( $k, $remove)) {
        unset( $params[$k]);
    }
}

$url = $parts['path'] . ((count( $params) > 0) ? '?' . http_build_query( $params) : '');
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$result = explode('?', $url)[0];
```

for a php version lower than php 5.4:

```
$tmp = explode('?', $url);
$result = $tmp[0];
```

Comment: I get this message with this code "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in ... line 26"

Comment: @mistertodd: Because your php version is lower than 5.4, tests the second version.

Comment: @casimir have you a solution for directly cleaning specific parts? (my edit above)

Answer (score 0):

```
list($done) = explode("?", $url);
```

This snytax also works in PHP 5.3 and lower

Comment: works for me :-) - I will see what the other users will provide.