# How to remove the $_GET variables from previous URL in PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

The scenario is I'm showing a javascript pop-up to user. If the user clicks on Ok button I'm redirecting the user to some webpage containing one form. Now after filling up the form when user clicks on submit button I'm getting the same $_GET variable array which I used to pass after confirmation of user. Now actually what I want to do is remove the $_GET array after submission of form. How should I achieve this? I tried and googled for the solution but couldn't find the right one. Any help would be highly appreciated. 
For your reference I'm putting my code as below:

```
/*The HTML code snippet*/

<input type="radio" name="generate_paper" id="generate_own_paper" value="own" data-href="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/tests/manual_test_questions.php?op=next&test_id=101&test_no_questions=50"/>  <label for="generate_paper_own">Own Paper</label>

/*The Javascript Code snippet*/

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $("#generate_own_paper").click(function(e) { 
    var ans=confirm("Do you want to generate own test questions?");
    if(!ans) {
      return false;
    } else {
      window.location.href = $('#generate_own_paper').attr('data-href');
    }    
  });
});
</script>
```

I'm not giving the form details as it is a very big PHP form. Can anyone help me in my issue, please? If you want any further details I can provide you the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This have been asked before [Beautiful way to remove GET-variables with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251582/beautiful-way-to-remove-get-variables-with-php)

Accepted answer says:

```
$url = strtok($url, '?');
```

Comment: First, instead of copying an answer, you should just close an answer as a duplicate. Second, I *think* the OP needs a JavaScript solution.