# Remove query_arg from url

Tags: php

I am adding parameters to my url using

```
<?php 
  echo esc_attr( add_query_arg( 'past_events', '' ) ); 
?>
```

when a link is clicked. This works perfectly but how would I remove past-events from the URL if another button is clicked?

Comment: `add_query_arg()` is not a php core function. It is a WordPress function. So, the example is not a generic purpose code.  Moreover, the wording of this question is poor and doesn't really expose the problem. Finally, the question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251582/beautiful-way-to-remove-get-variables-with-php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$url = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $url);
```

Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270683/829533