# how to reset the dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: php, checkbox

i am making a form with dynamically created checkboxes using from my database and some another static checkboxes how to reset the dynamically created checkboxes without affecting the static checkboxes here is my code...

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function submit()
{
document.getElementById('form1').submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1"method="get" name="form1">
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('sample database');
$selectbrand="select brandname from brand group by brandname";
$resultbrand=mysql_query($selectbrand);
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($resultbrand))
{
$brands=$res['brandname'];
?>
<?php echo $brands?>:<input type="checkbox"name="<?php echo $brands?>"id="<?php echo         
$brands?>" value="<?php echo $brands?>" onclick="submit();"<?php   
if($_GET[$brands]):$ar[]=$_GET[$brands]?>checked="checked" <?php endif;?>><br>
<?php
}?>
<input type="reset"  value="clear" name="reset1"value="clear">

<input type="checkbox"name="checkbox1" onclick="submit();" <?php        
if($_GET['checkbox1']):?>checked="checked" <?php endif;?>>24 hrs
<input type="checkbox"name="checkbox2" onclick="submit();" <?php      
if($_GET['checkbox2']):?>checked="checked" <?php endif;?>>2 days
<input type="checkbox"name="checkbox3" onclick="submit();" <?php  
if($_GET['checkbox3']):?>checked="checked" <?php endif;?>>3 days
<input type="reset" name="reset2" value="clear">
</form>
</body>
</html>

 <?php
$c=count($ar);
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++)
{
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('sample database');
$selectquery="select * from brand where brandname='$ar[$i] '";
$result=mysql_query($selectquery);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$n=$row['brandname'];
echo $n;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't see any dynamically created checkboxes (which would indincate javascript). just statically created ones.

Comment: i dynamically created from database

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to control one group of inputs is to incorporate Javascript and set a single class (or data-attributes) for that group. You can then attach an event to the faux-reset button and use Javascript to select only that class of inputs to reset.

See:

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector <-- how to select a group of elements with the same class, using jQuery

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml <-- how to reset an entire form in pure Javascript

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where to implement the javascript because you didn't explain how you were going to use them but here is how I would accomplish it.

First put all the dynamically created id's into an array.

```
global $brandids;
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($resultbrand))
{
$brands=$res['brandname'];
$brandids[] = $brands; //this pushes the id into the brandids array
```

Next, you would have this php code write a complete javascript function or inside of one

```
$i = 0;
while ($brandids[$i] != null) {
echo 'document.getElementById("' . ($brandids[$i] . '").checked = false;';
$i++;
}
```

Comment: i also want that when i click on clear button some parameter from the urls delete

Comment: Did my solution work for you? And check this out for your url question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251582/beautiful-way-to-remove-get-variables-with-php

Comment: Would you mind marking it as the correct answer please? Thank you